# Technical name for code not part of any function

Tags: javascript, python, scripting, programming-languages

What would be the technical term for code in scripting languages which is not part of any function and is executed first when the script is imported?

For example, in python:

```
import anything

#what is the technical name for this code?
a = 1
doABackFlip()

def myFunction():
  #Not this code since it is part of a function
  b = 2
  runSomething()

class myClass():
  #This is in a class so not this code either
```

In javascript:

```
<script>
  //What is the technical name of this code?
  a = 1
  doABarrelRoll()

  function myFunction() {
    //Not this stuff. Part of a function again
    doSomethingCool()
    }
</script>
```

I am looking specifically for a one or two word term for this code. It would be best if it were either a descriptor in common use or better yet, something coined in some academic paper back in the 60s.

Comment: In Python, we have the term module-level, so that code would be module-level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if the code running outside of functions have a specific name but the "space" they run in do have a common name in various languages: it's called the **[global scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28computer_science%29#Global_scope)**.

Typically the code running in global scope are simply called *"code running in global scope"*.

Comment: *Code running in global scope* does seem to capture what this code is pretty well. Maybe the *global frame* is a slightly more terse terminology? I am going to keep this question open longer though to see whether there is a more technical term out there

Comment: Some languages refer to "global context" since in some languages "scope" has very specific meaning. But the word "context" means so many different but related things to different languages that it's even more troublesome to use. I think "global frame" is a good name for it but languages like tcl already call it "global scope". As long as you define what you mean before using a term I think you should be fine. Heck, even "stack frame" is just a commonly understood shorthand for the more correct terminology: "activation record".

Comment: For my purposes, `global frame` is what I am looking for. Thanks for getting me there!

Answer (score 1):

I really like your question and I cannot give a definitive answer to it. However, I'd like to reason a bit here.

When you write a parser for an imperative language you will encounter something like a `StatementList` -- which is a list of Statements. So that everything within the surrounding "block" (i.e. functions, methods, but also the loop-bodies or just `{` and `}` within other blocks in c-like languages) will be represented as a `StatementList`. So to me the question here is: how is the surrounding Node in the abstract syntax tree (AST) called. And so far all I have seen is: "Program".

Also that is the name this statement-list has in [Pascal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_%28programming_language%29#Hello_world).

Comment: +1 for looking into the labels used in ASTs. It seems like there must be a more specific somewhat-mathematical name for the "Program" though

Comment: Yes, I'm with you on that. As I said very interesting question, never thought about that, despite the fact that my first language was BASIC, followed by Pascal ;D